# Get ASP.net username of Authenticated User and redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to redirect based on the username of authenticated users, and if the name matches something, to redirect the page. But the code below seems to just send "Admin" to the homepage, instead of the account page.

Is this even possible?

```
    Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

    If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then

        Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

        If CurrentUser IsNot Nothing Then

            If CurrentUser.IsApproved = False Or CurrentUser.IsLockedOut = True Then
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
            End If

            If CurrentUser Is "Admin" Then
                Response.Redirect("/account/")
            End If

            Response.Redirect("/home/")
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try changing your test from `If CurrentUser Is "Admin" Then` to `If User.Identity.Name = "Admin" Then` ?

Comment: Is admin a username or rolename?

Comment: Changing to User.Identity.Name did the job! Thanks